Is it possible to copy Skitch from old Macbook Air (M2) to new Macbook Pro (M4) without using Time Machine?
So I am a die-hard Skitch fan (the original screenshot program...not whatever the hell it morphed into). Been using it since 2011? I have "carried it over" from Macbook to Macbook over the past decade and some change.
I want to know if there's a way to copy Skitch and associated files on my current Macbook Air M2 onto a USB-C drive and then install it on the new Macbook Pro M4 I am getting.
Yes, I know I can do Time Machine, however, I have used this M2 Air as a test bed for countless Docker/etc programs from Github. I prefer to start off with a clean slate on the M4 Macbook Pro. So, I do not think I can simply back up that program and not the system settings (I have installed a ton of stuff from Github that I'm not 100% on from several perspectives including security).
And I do not have the original .DMG file.
And I know I'm on Apple Silicon and I first downloaded Skitch on the Intel Macbook Pro I had back in the day. So, there's potentially that issue as well. Skitch works perfectly fine on my M2 Macbook Air. However, unsure if I can save it to a USB and then "install" it on the M4 Macbook Pro.
And yes, I have tested other screenshot programs. And "meh."

Did you ask the developer if it can be done?

Welcome to Ask Different. You write: "I have "carried it over" from Macbook to Macbook over the past decade and some change." Did you do so in the past with Time Machine? Also, you write: "However, unsure if I can save it to a USB and then "install" it on the M4 Macbook Pro." Have you tried but it didn't work? Or what's stopping you from trying? You can simply copy the app over to your new Mac (using a USB-C drive) and check if it launches/works (important: format the USB-C drive with APFS or HFS+, not extFS or some other "non-native" format).

You can simply restore the Skitch app to your Applications folder using Time Machine. You don't have to restore anything else. Go to your Applications folder; enter TM, browse to a date when you had the app: click on Restore. If the app does have folders in Library/Application Support that are essential, you can restore those, as well.
